# SQL Server stored procedure to insert with check from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables

**Table 1**

```
userid int
username varchar(25)
password varchar(25)
siteid int (foreign key)
```

**Table 2**

```
siteid int
siteurl varchar(200)
```

I want to fire an insert with a stored procedure

I am getting username, password and siteurl as parameters.

Now when I want to insert the data, I need to check conditions

- no duplicate usernames allowed per siteurl
- if username exists and site url also matches then it should not allow to insert
- if username exists but different siteurl then it will allow to insert

At present I am fetching first site id and then passing site id as param, but this means traffic between site and database will be double.

But if same happens with single stored procedure then there will be difference

Comment: Sorry ... what ?!?! I don't understand what you're asking.... are you asking whether using a stored procedure will be beneficial? Are you asking how to write that stored procedure? What is it??

Comment: i already wrote sp but need some help

below is sample

create proc addnewuser
username
password
siteid

begin
if(not exists(select userid from userlogin where userlogin.username=username and userlogin.siteid=siteid))
begin
....
end
end

but i want pass siteurl and get siteid and then compare

Comment: Then you should **SHOW US** that stored procedure and **explain** what the issues are that you're facing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE addnewuser 
  @username VARCHAR(25),
  @password VARCHAR(25),
  @siteurl  VARCHAR(200)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                FROM userlogin u JOIN sites s 
                  ON u.siteid = s.siteid 
               WHERE u.username = @username
                 AND s.siteurl = @siteurl)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO sites (siteurl) 
    VALUES (@siteurl);
  INSERT INTO userlogin (username, password, siteid) 
    VALUES (@username, @password, SCOPE_IDENTITY());
END
ELSE
  RAISERROR ('User already exists', 16, 1);
GO
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f400b/1)** demo. *Uncomment last `EXEC` and click `Build Schema` to see that it won't let you insert the same user again*

Comment: I often do a very similar thing in my stored procs, but I perform my checks at the beginning of the proc like I would guard clauses on any given method. RAISERROR will allow you to provide a useful error message as to why your insert can't be performed and which of the clauses failed.